# Convert POSIX pattern to PCRE in php (eregi to preg_match)

Tags: php, regex, posix, pcre

```
eregi("<input[[:space:]]+type=[\"\']?hidden[\"\']?[[:space:]]+value=[\"\']?([^> \"\']+)[\"\']?[[:space:]]+name=[\"\']?(form_page_origine|form_origine|page_origine)[\"\']?[[:space:]]*/?>"
```

How can I switch it to preg_match? thank.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php you will find all the informations you need.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I write a good answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).